# Insert/Update bulk data to sql table in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I have one product table with consist of product number , price and currency.
I upload the data through excel file with the data.
When i upload the data then i create a list at back end with all data from excel and then send entire list to server to update/insert data in the table.

```
               foreach(Product value in item)
                {
                    Product p = context.Product.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductNumber == value.ProductNumber && p.CurrencyId == value.CurrencyId);
                    if (p!= null)
                    {

                        context.Entry<Product>(p).Property(p => p.ProductPrice).IsModified = true;
                        p.ProductPrice = value.ProductPrice ;

                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        context.Product.Add(value);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
```

But as the data increases (Product increase) then upload takes a lot of time.
Any suggestion to optimize this? One stuff i am thinking is of Index on productnumber and currency column.

Answer (score 0):

The performance issue is not caused because of the index (Of course if no index exists, this will also help) but because of the number of database round-trip your code is performing.

For every product:

- You check if the product exists (1 database round-trip)
- You insert/update the product (1 database round-trip)

So if you upload 10,000 products from your excel file, you will perform 20,000 database round-trip which is insane.

There are some tricks which may help the performance a little bit like adding multiple products to insert with AddRange instead of Add, but you would end up with the same performance issue caused by the number of database round-trip.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library allows to dramatically improve performance by performing:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge

Example:

```
// Insert or Update using ProductNumber && CurrencyId as the Key
ctx.BulkMerge(list, operation =>
{
    operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new {x.ProductNumber, x.CurrencyId};
});
```

Comment: Jonathan : thanks for your answer but i see that extension is on license cost based. If same stuff was available over nuget then it would have nice.

Comment: At this moment, only my library from NuGet is available to solve this kind of issue. However, you can improve for free the insertion performance using the following library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6/

Comment: Fortunately there are NuGet package available now for free, please try.

[EF6.BulkInsert.MySql 6.1.0.6** durch Vitor Ortuondo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BulkInsert.EF6.MySql/); 

[BulkInsert.EF6.MySql 6.0.4** durch Kinshines](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EF6.BulkInsert.MySql/)